# cloud endpoints oauth cannot Sign out

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-cloud-endpoints

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/consume_js?#signing_out

As mentioned by google in the above link there is no sign out function. Has anyone achieved emulating sign out?

I was expecting to set gapi.auth.setToken(null) and then call gapi.auth.authorize with immediate as false (as below) to force the sign-in popup. Annoyingly this immediately signs in instead.

```
gapi.auth.authorize({client_id: this.CLIENT_ID,
                scope: this.SCOPES, immediate: false},
                authCallback);
```

The behaviour I'm expecting is to be presented with the google authentication popup when I clear the token and call gapi.auth.authorize with mode false. Currently doing this causes the popup to flash open and close before immediately signing in without allowing credentials to be entered.

Comment: sign out from what, google or your app? it might be worth explaining a bit more what behaviour you want your users to experience. Don't confuse OAuth and access tokens with authentication and sessions.

Comment: sign out from google